# ¿Como puedo hacer que un Label muestre un texto largo sin cortarse?

Tags: python, python-3.7, label

Necesito ayuda :(
Es que intenté hacer algo pero me sale mal
Hize una app para que cuando alguien escriba alguna frase, luego se cambien los caracteres y aparesca en un cuadro de abajo, pero el cuadro no se muestra bien y el texto del label no aparece completo, o si quito el width y el heigth se me va fuera de la ventana y tampoco lo muestra todo

Este es el codigo del label

```
traduccion = tk.Label(ventana,textvariable=resul)
traduccion.config(font=("Verdana",11),width=30, height=10)
traduccion.place(x=50,y=230)
```

[image: App]

Probé con quitar el width y el height pero igual me aparece mal

```
traduccion = tk.Label(ventana,textvariable=resul)
traduccion.config(font=("Verdana",11))
traduccion.place(x=50,y=230)
```

Además me preguntaba como puedo hacer para que en el cuadro de Input de arriba se pudiera hacer más grande para que así lo muestre todo en caso de que sea largo, eso se puede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno alfinal encontré la solución yo mismo

La pondré en caso de que alguien más tenga esta duda
Solo hay que poner el comando "wraplength=numero" que limita la cantidad de caracteres mostrados en una linea, pero creo que depende de los pixeles, aún tengo que verlo pero se los dejo para que ustedes mismos lo vean.

Lo puse en el código, y también agregué otro "anchor=n"
Eso es para modificar el lugar de donde aparece cargado el texto (izquierda, derecha, arriba, abajo, etc)
[Como posicionar el texto de un label a la izquierda en tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132969/como-posicionar-el-texto-de-un-label-a-la-izquierda-en-tkinter) (aquí encontré una página con estas cosas)

También hay que ir arreglando el "width" y el "height" en la linea Config para que concuerde con el "wraplenght"

```
traduccion = tk.Label(ventana,textvariable=resul,wraplength=360,anchor="n")
traduccion.config(bg="#022C48", fg="#E59866",font=("Verdana",10,"bold","italic"),width=45, height=15)
traduccion.place(x=40,y=210)
```